# How to override global border color styles for disabled Material UI TextField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to override the global style for the Mui TextField components that are disabled, but I can't get the border color to change.

I've managed to change the label color if the field is disabled, but not the border color. Here is what I have so far:

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    // For label
    MuiInputLabel: {
      root: {
        '&$disabled': {
          color: '#000000',
        },
      },
    },
    // For border color of field (doesn't work)
    MuiTextField: {
      root: {
        '&$disabled': {
          borderColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I've tried all kinds of variations, including,

```
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        fieldset: {
          borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
        },
      }
    }
```

But this only changes the border color of non-disabled fields. What am I doing wrong here?
Here is how it looks:
[image: img]

Comment: Have you tried overriding the OutlineInput?

Comment: I've tried overriding `MuiTextField`, `MuiInput` and other things that seemed to have something to do with Input, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The border is getting from the `fieldset` element. You can style if based on your needs:

```
MuiInputBase: {
  root: {
    "&$disabled": {
      '& fieldset.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
        borderColor: "blue",
        background: "grey"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-styling-disabled-textfield-ckp14?file=/demo.js

Here is a "walkthrough" for how to do it yourself:

1. Check the html output:
   [image]
2. Open the image in new tab to check the marks.
   As you can see - the label is actually not a parent of the fieldset tag, which is the one that draws the border.
3. The fieldset is inside the `div.MuiInputBase`, which is also disabled, so I had to add the `&$disabled` on the root of the `MuiInputBase`.
4. As for the `& fieldset` - the `fieldset` element is a child-element fo the `MuiInputBase` - so the space between the `&` and the tag-name means this is a child-element.
5. The fieldset element has the `MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline` so I used it as the relevant selector. You could probably just use `.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-disabled fieldset` without the last-selector. Try it :-).

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I have a question, how did you know to choose `MuiInputBase` instead of `MuiTextField` and how did you come up with `'& fieldset.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline`?

Comment: @MikeK great :) I'll add the explanation on how I got to this solution inside the answer.